CS-Script Or Like Tool - To allow calling script from C# program and change passed parameters?
I have written a program where I would like to be able to run a C# piece of code from within a C# program.  It needs to be able to function something like a regular function call (pass parameters, run some code, and possibly either return a value or modify the parameters passed in) - allowing if, loops, etc.  The catch is that this will not be compiled code.  This 'code' will be entered into the program by the user (yes - user entered code :0 ).  So - what I need is the ability to run uncompiled user entered code from a C# compiled .net application.
The added complication is that I also need to be able to pass parameters to the script and have them modify those variables/objects.  In particular, I need to be able to modify DataTables that are created in the main C# program - that includes adding, modifying, and deleting columns and rows in those datatables.
Can this be done using CS-Script?  Or is there another "scripting" solution out there that can do this better than CS-Script?

We don't allow signatures in posts here. Your username is displayed in the lower right of every question and/or answer you post here, and at the end of every comment. Signatures are just unnecessary clutter.

Ken - understood.  Makes sense.  I will make sure I do not do it again.

CS Script is fine to do that. There are also different scripting engines - I think I saw one for Lua ... I used csx with rozlyn some years ago and haven't touched it since. I would expect an even smoother experience today.

CS Script would have the advantage that you can use the same types and libs in the Script and your program. I recommend to do a poc that roughly covers all your K.O.-Requirements.

Ok - as "Fildor" noted - CS-Script works really well.
I downloaded the nuget package - played with it - and within 45 minutes had a sample test program that will do exactly what I want it to.
CS-Script is surprisingly powerful and easy to use.   Well - now i have a Lot of reading to do on it - to get it fully ready for what I want to do.
Thank you to Fildor for confirming that it should work!
